# Set Up SQUID proxy,but unable to authenticate

Tags: linux, squid

I am trying to set up proxy,but its not configuring properly. I have set my 'Squid.conf' file.I am trying to block 'yahoo' on my nearest machin with IP-address - 192.168.1.58.
But though I able to see 'yahoo' page.
PFA 'squid.conf' file.

```
----------------------------
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl localhost src ::1/128
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32
acl to_localhost dst ::1/128

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0-192.168.1.92 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7 # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10 # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 70 # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 # multiling http
acl CONNECT method GET POST CONNECT
acl Proxy_Port myport 3128
acl home src 192.168.1.58/255.255.255.0
acl bad url_regex -i yahoo.com
acl good url_regex -i google.com google.co.in

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow Proxy_Port
http_access allow home
http_access allow good
http_access deny bad


# And finally deny all other access to this proxy

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128
http_port 8080 transparent

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 7000 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
cache_effective_user squid
cache_effective_group squid
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

squid reads from top to bottom and stops when it hits a match.

and putting in sites 1x1 is tough. I found this example that says it well

**create a file listing the bad sites**

File: /usr/local/etc/restricted-sites.squid

yahoo.com

This can then be used to always block the restricted sites

**AND then IN squid.conf itself
Add this to the bottom of the ACL section of squid.conf**

acl BadSites  dstdomain "/usr/local/etc/restricted-sites.squid"

**Add this at the top of the http_access section of squid.conf**

http_access deny BadSites`

---END conf

you having

http_access allow localnet
at top allows everything

and

acl home src 192.168.1.58/255.255.255.0

should probably either be

acl home src 192.168.1.58/255.255.255.255

or

acl home src 192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0